# Conference / Board Members / Institute

Tags: meaning

I have a couple of questions about this appreciation letter. 
http://www.writinghelp-central.com/appreciation-letter.html

> I would like to take this opportunity to express my heartfelt thanks to you for your very active participation in *our recent conference* in Montreal on the "future of aviation". *The Chairman and Board Members* have also asked me to pass on their sincere appreciation for  your efforts in supporting *the Institute* in this important undertaking.

1. Am I correct in understanding that "conference" means academic conference in this context?
2. As for "chairman and board members", which one is correct, chairman and board members of "conference" or chairman and board members of "the institute"?
3. Am I correct in understanding that "institute" means research institute in this context?
4. Am I correct in understanding that "our conference" means "conference of the institute" and Peter Smithfield is a President and CEO of the institute?

Comment: 2: of the institute.  - the rest of your assumptins are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes. *"[...] for your efforts in supporting the Institute [...]"* The mention of "institute" supports that assumption.
2. Conferences do not usually have Chairpersons or Boards. So they belong to the organisation (=institute.)
3. Most likely yes, since they are holding conferences about scientific topics. But it could also be a commercial/professional organization (ie. association of aircraft manufacturers or such.)
4. Yes. The sender of this letter is the institute; the signer of a letter speaks (or writes) on behalf of the sending organization, and as such mentions his position in, or in relation to, the organisation. So yes, you can assume that he is CEO and Presdent of the organization.